# jquery validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the plugin from here: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

and I am wondering if anyone has any code that will allow me to compare 2 form fields and validate that `field_1` must be larger than `field_2`?

I am initiated the validate method like:

```
$("#frmValidate").validate({
    meta: "validate"
});
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in a simple two-step process:

1. [Declare your own validation method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod). In that method you would compare the two input elements.
2. Reference the validation method in one of the two input elements.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem is, I am not experienced in this type of validation creation.

Comment: jQuery.validator.addMethod("greaterThanStartPrice", function(value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || (parseFloat(value) >= $(param).val());
   }, "Amount must be greater than start price");

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the validation method, something like that:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "greaterThan",
    function(value,element,params) {
        if (value > $(params).val()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    },
    "Wrong"
);
```

And then use it in validation.

```
$('#my_form').validate({
        rules: {
            'field1': {
                required: true,
                greaterThan: '#field2'
            }
        }
});
```